# can not create batch drawable import . when i go to new, it is not available on the list

Tags: android

can not create batch drawable import . when i go to new, it is not available on the list. the list ending at resource bundle, no batch drawable import I'm using android studio 3.4.2

[Picture showing full list available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYjcn.png)

Answer (score 1):

install Batch Drawable Import from Intellij plugin

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio click on Resource Manager in left side tab.

[image: Drag and drop batch files]

Then select your batch of images drag and drop in Drawable section shown in images.

[image: Rename and import]